# Scale an entire SVG image to a new size without having to update the sizes of all the objects in it

Tags: image, svg, resize, scale

I have an SVG image that specifies a specific height and width.   All the objects in the SVG image are created to use this width and height.  Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="600" height="600">
  <g>
    <circle cx="300" cy="300" r="295" fill="red" stroke="black" stroke-width="10"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Which makes a 600 pixel red circle with a black border:

[image: 600 pixel red circle with black border]

How do I scale this SVG image (to say 200x200) without having to go through and update all the objects (in this case just the red circle) contained within it?

Answer (score 8):

To resize an SVG image you need to introduce a `viewBox` attribute that contains the the original size pixels.  Then you can change the width and height to whatever you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 600 600">
  <g>
    <circle cx="300" cy="300" r="295" fill="red" stroke="black" stroke-width="10"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

That way the coordinate system to which the image is drawn is still the original 600x600, but the image displays scaled to 200x200.

[image: 200 pixel red circle with black border]

Answer (score -1):

Alternate method: assuming that all these SVG images are individual files, you can use either `<object>`, `<embed>` or `<img>` tag to reference this SVG file, then set `width=200` and `height=200` to rescale it.

Eg: `<img src="path/to/somefile.svg" width="200" height="200"...../>`